# How does OSPF sense the physical media?

Tags: networking, ospf

For different physical media types, OSPF behaves differently about electing a Designated Router or not. For example, non-multiaccess media links such as serial Point to Point do not need election for a designated router. The question is how does OSPF sense the physical media?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's up to the hardware to tell OSPF what type it is.  This is specific to manufacturers and devices.

Comment: I think your response in general is correct, but I'm asking HOW OSPF communicates with the router interface regarding the media type, like some flags or bit codes?

Comment: That's up to the specific implementation.  It's different on different operating systems

Comment: Thanks, Ron! Your answer is helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to sense the physical medium. Multi-access or not is an intrinsic property of the network interface type.

Probably the most common interface type, Ethernet is always a multi-access network type, even it directly connects two hosts. A simple serial interface is always point to point.